# Custom Glossary Style

Tags: glossaries

My glossaries package setting:

```
\usepackage[%
nonumberlist,
toc,
nopostdot,
style=altlist,
nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{\textup{#1}}}
```

produces:

[image]

And I want it similar to [Glossaries User Manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)

[image]

(Left margin on the left, and the paragraphs following the first are not indented.)

I checked the original .tex file but quickly confused myself.

What settings would enable me to have the above style?

Further, are there settings to customize: (1) vertical spacing between label and description; (2) horizontal spacing for the left margin; (3) the vertical spaces between entries?

Comment: I would suggest looking into the following link, http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/
then if you do not find what you are looking for there, try http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec%3anewglossarystyle from the full user guide

Comment: @Elad Thanks, but they are not helpful in my case. What I need is the actual commands to style as I want. For example, what command allows me to indent the description text?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you're defining your entries and what class you're using as these can make a difference to the appearance. For example, if the entries are defined like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
nonumberlist,
toc,
nopostdot,
style=altlist,
nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{\textup{#1}}}

\newglossaryentry{accept}{name={accept},
 description={(1) (of a game-try or a slam-try or an invitation to 
take a particular action) make the call suggested or invited, or a 
move in that direction\glspar (2) (of a transfer) make the call
suggested by the transfer}
}

\newglossaryentry{ace+spaces}{name={ace and spaces},
 description={(adjective for hand) rich in high honors but weak
 in lower honors and intermediates, and not having an apparent 
source of tricks at notrump}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{accept}; \gls{ace+spaces}.

\printglossary
```

Then the glossary looks like this:

[image: image of glossary]

If you've used child entries like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
nonumberlist,
toc,
nopostdot,
style=altlist,
subentrycounter,
nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{\textup{#1}}}

\newglossaryentry{accept}{name={accept},
 description={\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{accept1}{parent={accept},
 description={(of a game-try or a slam-try or an invitation to
take a particular action) make the call suggested or invited, or a
move in that direction}}

\newglossaryentry{accept2}{parent={accept},
 description={(of a transfer) make the call
suggested by the transfer}
}

\newglossaryentry{ace+spaces}{name={ace and spaces},
 description={(adjective for hand) rich in high honors but weak
 in lower honors and intermediates, and not having an apparent
source of tricks at notrump}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{accept1}; \gls{accept2}; \gls{ace+spaces}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Then the glossary looks like this:

[image: image of glossary]

(The same as the first example.)

This matches the layout of the glossary in the user manual that you want to reproduce. Since this doesn't match the image you supplied from your document, then there's something in your document that's interfering with the default behaviour. Without knowing what that is, it's impossible to say how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware that my other settings might be interfering in some way; that is why I am not trying to fix my problem by altering the other states but looking for the commands in the ´glossaries´ package. (E.g. see my example to change the label font.)